Palantir Foundry import xlsx files [Excel from NAS]
I am in Palantir Foundry. I need to create a connection to a NAS folder that takes the xlsx files inside it.
The problem is that I do not create a dataset but a list of the xlsx files I connected to.
How do I transform this list into a dataset that can be used in my pipeline?

You can ingest all the Excels files into one dataset only, which is simpler than creating one dataset per file.
EDIT: Then you have one dataset of excels files, and you can just process those excel the way you want (e.g. in Transforms, Pipeline builder, etc.).
In your specific case, for example if you have 2000 excels with the same structure, you can store them all in one dataset and then parse them the same way (via any of the solution listed above and below)
There are many ways to extract tabular data from a schemaless dataset containing Microsoft Excel files in Foundry, including Pipeline Builder, Python file-based transforms using open-source libraries like openpyxl, and Java file-based transforms using open-source libraries like Apache POI.
See https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/microsoft-excel/transforms-excel-parser/
Or look at similar answers: XLSX file extraction in Palantir Foundry
Or a relevant video to help you there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKIZPYuQKqg

ok, and then? How can i combine them?

Edited further. Please provide more information in your original post if this doesn't help. The ask is not very clear.
